# Getting silent vs being silent

Tags: causative-get

According to me, get in this context can be used.  For example if we talk about a  person who  a moment ago was  talking and then he suddenly stopped. So his condition changed from talking to not at all. But be may also be used if u do not want to describe the changing condition but  the person's present condition which is silent.  I am much confused right now.Please tell me the exact difference. And also point me to a site which has detailed explanation about the difference between Get and Be. Thanks in advance. And please answer this question because it holds a great importance to me.

Answer (score 2):

To "get *adjective*" usually means "to become *adjective*, **as a process**".  For example,

> My nephew got taller over the summer.

or

> The animals get sick if they do not have enough to eat.  But they will get well again if they are given good food.

It does not sound natural with things that happen instantaneously, like "he got silent".  More natural is "he **became** silent" or "he **fell** silent".

The correct and idiomatic usage of "get ____" is very difficult and subtle, and overuse of "get ____" is a hallmark of English language learners.  For that reason, I recommend that new English speakers learn a few stock phrases like *get sick, get well, get better*, and not try to use it as a general replacement for *become* until they have a feel for its idiomatic usage.

Comment: It's definitely *fall* silent. ;o)

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with *It does not sound natural with things that happen instantaneously*. Perhaps add *he got quieter* as a correct if somewhat clumsy-sounding alternative?

Comment: I have another thought, which is that *becoming silent* is about *stopping* doing something (i.e. talking, or whatever noise-making was in progress). I think *get* doesn't work for .. well, stopping making a noise is the opposite of *getting something*?

Comment: I'd say that getting + adjective means ***becoming***. That said, getting silent is not great but it could be colloquial. Fall silent is elegant and literary. Bob Dylan: Get sick, get well, Hang around an ink well, Subterranean Homesick Blues. Ever seen the video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGxjIBEZvx0